# Vaadin8 and wildfly 21 reported with thread leaks

Tags: java, web-applications, vaadin8

We are running the vaadin8 application in wildlfy21 and we are encoutered with widfly thread count is increasing frequently and it causing the unexpected behaviour to the system, can you please hlep us how to resolve this ?

Thanks in advace.

Below is the log form the thread dump.

```
Thread 17901: (state = BLOCKED)
 - sun.misc.Unsafe.park(boolean, long) @bci=0 (Compiled frame; information may be imprecise)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(java.lang.Object) @bci=14, line=175 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.parkAndCheckInterrupt() @bci=1, line=836 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireQueued(java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$Node, int) @bci=67, line=870 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquire(int) @bci=17, line=1199 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$NonfairSync.lock() @bci=21, line=209 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock.lock() @bci=4, line=285 (Compiled frame)
 - com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.lockSession(com.vaadin.server.WrappedSession) @bci=52, line=714 (Compiled frame)
 - com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.findOrCreateVaadinSession(com.vaadin.server.VaadinRequest) @bci=15, line=760 (Compiled frame)
 - com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.findVaadinSession(com.vaadin.server.VaadinRequest) @bci=2, line=605 (Compiled frame)
 - com.blujaysolutions.tmff.vaadin.servlets.TMFFVaadinServletService.findVaadinSession(com.vaadin.server.VaadinRequest) @bci=2, line=58 (Compiled frame)
 - com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(com.vaadin.server.VaadinRequest, com.vaadin.server.VaadinResponse) @bci=10, line=1631 (Compiled frame)
 - com.blujaysolutions.tmff.vaadin.servlets.TMFFVaadinServletService.handleRequest(com.vaadin.server.VaadinRequest, com.vaadin.server.VaadinResponse) @bci=6, line=47 (Compiled frame)
 - com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.service(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse) @bci=81, line=464 (Compiled frame)
 - com.blujaysolutions.tmff.vaadin.servlets.TMFFAppVaadinServlet.service(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse) @bci=7, line=97 (Compiled frame)
 - javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(javax.servlet.ServletRequest, javax.servlet.ServletResponse) @bci=39, line=590 (Compiled frame)
 - io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange) @bci=143, line=74 (Compiled frame)
 - io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(javax.servlet.ServletRequest, javax.servlet.ServletResponse) @bci=124, line=129 (Compiled frame)
 - io.undertow.websockets.jsr.JsrWebSocketFilter.doFilter(javax.servlet.ServletRequest, javax.servlet.ServletResponse, javax.servlet.FilterChain) @bci=315, line=173 (Compiled frame)
 - io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(javax.servlet.ServletRequest, javax.servlet.ServletResponse, javax.servlet.FilterChain) @bci=60, line=61 (Compiled frame)
 - io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(javax.servlet.ServletRequest, javax.servlet.ServletResponse) @bci=149, line=131 (Compiled frame)
 - com.blujaysolutions.tmff.servlets.TMFFAPPAuthenticateFilter.doFilter(javax.servlet.ServletRequest, javax.servlet.ServletResponse, javax.servlet.FilterChain) @bci=326, line=157 (Compiled frame)
 - io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(javax.servlet.ServletRequest, javax.servlet.ServletResponse, javax.servlet.FilterChain) @bci=60, line=61 (Compiled frame)
 - io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(javax.servlet.ServletRequest, javax.servlet.ServletResponse) @bci=149, line=131 (Compiled frame)
 - io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange) @bci=122, line=84 (Compiled frame)
 - io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange) @bci=104, line=62 (Compiled frame)
 - io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange) @bci=62, line=68 (Compiled frame)
 - io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange) @bci=19, line=36 (Compiled frame)
 - org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange) @bci=118, line=78 (Compiled frame)
 - io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange) @bci=27, line=43 (Compiled frame)
 - io.undertow.servlet.handlers.RedirectDirHandler.handleRequest(io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange) @bci=152, line=68 (Compiled frame)
 - io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange) @bci=101, line=132 (Compiled frame)
 - io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange) @bci=40, line=57 (Compiled frame)
 - io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange) @bci=27, line=43 (Compiled frame)
 - io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange) @bci=21, line=46 (Compiled frame)
 - io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange) @bci=99, line=64 (Compiled frame)
 - io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange) @bci=58, line=60 (Compiled frame)
 - io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange) @bci=51, line=77 (Compiled frame)
 - io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange) @bci=39, line=50 (Compiled frame)
 - io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange) @bci=14, line=43 (Compiled frame)
 - io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange) @bci=27, line=43 (Compiled frame)
 - org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange) @bci=16, line=61 (Compiled frame)
 - io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange) @bci=27, line=43 (Compiled frame)
 - org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.GlobalRequestControllerHandler.handleRequest(io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange) @bci=20, line=68 (Compiled frame)
 - io.undertow.servlet.handlers.SendErrorPageHandler.handleRequest(io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange) @bci=56, line=52 (Compiled frame)
 - io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange) @bci=27, line=43 (Compiled frame)
 - io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange, io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletRequestContext) @bci=108, line=269 (Compiled frame)
 - io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler, io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange, io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletRequestContext) @bci=3, line=78 (Compiled frame)
 - io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange, io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletRequestContext) @bci=6, line=133 (Compiled frame)
 - io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange, java.lang.Object) @bci=6, line=130 (Compiled frame)
 - io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange, java.lang.Object) @bci=42, line=48 (Compiled frame)
 - io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange, java.lang.Object) @bci=20, line=43 (Compiled frame)
 - org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(io.undertow.servlet.api.ThreadSetupHandler$Action, io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange, java.lang.Object) @bci=127, line=105 (Compiled frame)
 - org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction$$Lambda$907.call(io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange, java.lang.Object) @bci=10 (Compiled frame)
 - org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(io.undertow.servlet.api.ThreadSetupHandler$Action, io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange, java.lang.Object) @bci=15, line=1530 (Compiled frame)
 - org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction$$Lambda$908.call(io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange, java.lang.Object) @bci=10 (Compiled frame)
 - org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(io.undertow.servlet.api.ThreadSetupHandler$Action, io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange, java.lang.Object) @bci=15, line=1530 (Compiled frame)
 - org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction$$Lambda$908.call(io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange, java.lang.Object) @bci=10 (Compiled frame)
 - org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(io.undertow.servlet.api.ThreadSetupHandler$Action, io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange, java.lang.Object) @bci=15, line=1530 (Compiled frame)
 - org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction$$Lambda$908.call(io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange, java.lang.Object) @bci=10 (Compiled frame)
 - org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(io.undertow.servlet.api.ThreadSetupHandler$Action, io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange, java.lang.Object) @bci=15, line=1530 (Compiled frame)
 - org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction$$Lambda$908.call(io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange, java.lang.Object) @bci=10 (Compiled frame)
 - io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange, io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletRequestContext, io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain, javax.servlet.DispatcherType) @bci=33, line=249 (Compiled frame)
 - io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler, io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange, io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletRequestContext, io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain, javax.servlet.DispatcherType) @bci=6, line=78 (Compiled frame)
 - io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1$1.run() @bci=28, line=105 (Compiled frame)
 - java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(java.security.PrivilegedExceptionAction) @bci=0 (Compiled frame)
 - io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange) @bci=49, line=102 (Compiled frame)
 - io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(io.undertow.server.HttpHandler, io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange) @bci=8, line=387 (Compiled frame)
 - io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run() @bci=8, line=841 (Compiled frame)
 - org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run() @bci=17, line=35 (Compiled frame)
 - org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(java.lang.Runnable) @bci=39, line=1990 (Compiled frame)
 - org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(java.lang.Runnable) @bci=48, line=1486 (Compiled frame)
 - org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run() @bci=201, line=1377 (Compiled frame)
 - org.xnio.XnioWorker$WorkerThreadFactory$1$1.run() @bci=7, line=1280 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.Thread.run() @bci=11, line=748 (Compiled frame)


Thread 17178: (state = BLOCKED)
 - sun.misc.Unsafe.park(boolean, long) @bci=0 (Compiled frame; information may be imprecise)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(java.lang.Object, long) @bci=20, line=215 (Compiled frame)
 - org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run() @bci=442, line=1421 (Compiled frame)
 - org.xnio.XnioWorker$WorkerThreadFactory$1$1.run() @bci=7, line=1280 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.Thread.run() @bci=11, line=748 (Compiled frame)
```

How to fix the thread blockage and root cause.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.